# What factor decided which chariot race faction Byzantines supported?

Tags: byzantine-empire, sports

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chariot_racing#Byzantine_factions) Wikipedia article there were four very passionate factions of chariot race supporters labeled the blues, greens, reds and whites. As a person that has once been a young man that was very loyal to my local football team, I am very interested to read in this Wikipedia article that chariot racing was once the young man's sport of choice, with mindless clashes between rival factions not uncommon, not to dissimilar to football hooliganism of today.

However, I got my unique identity from my locality. I would be interested to know just how the young men of the early Byzantine period got their unique identities? What factor decided which faction a young man supported? Was it based on locality? political ideology? religion? or other?

Comment: with the roman system of patronage you were sort of born loyal to a team based on who your families patron was.  and yes the teams were based on social class and politics and even religion eventually.